# Ruby 1.9.3 UndefinedConversionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Up until recently everything was working fine on my machines but since a few days I keep getting an error `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+2713 from UTF-8 to US-ASCII` any time I post something from the browser to the server.

First since posts were involved I tried the most obvious thing with adding encoding to the database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  hostname: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: mikael
  password:
  database: dev
  encoding: utf8
```

If I install ruby-debug19 and ruby-debug-base19 and run rails with:

```
rails s --environment=development --debug
```

Now everything is working fine. How the hell am I supposed to find out the cause of the problem so that I may fix it?

**EDIT 1:**

```
1.9.3p0 :001 > Encoding.default_internal
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8> 
1.9.3p0 :002 > Encoding.default_external
 => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

**EDIT 2:**
If I run in production mode everything works fine.

Comment: `U+2713` is the checkmark (`utf8=✓`) that rails uses in latest versions to verify that you are able to work with UTF-8 data. sure you did not update anything?

Comment: Please run rails console and check `Encoding.default_internal` and `Encoding.default_external`.

Comment: Where does the error come from? Your code or somewhere deep inside Rails?

Comment: I've got the same issue, overtook a rails application of someone else and now I get UTF-8 encoding errors like that with my test suite, if you found a fix for that, please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a  [bug](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/5564) that has been reported in Rails 3.1.2 has a [workaround](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2011/11/17/rails-3-1-2-has-been-released) and the next release of 1.9.3 should fix the issue

Comment: Thats it and it looks like rails 3.2 has brought back the same old bug that was fixed in 3.1.2 or maybe it's a gem causing it.

Comment: The workaround link is not available, can you please re-post it?

Answer (score 15):

Try setting `LC_ALL` and `LANG` variable in your shell. Add these lines to your ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zprofile or somewhere similar - depending on your system.

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

You can get a list of all locales by running `locale -a`. At the end you should see something similar when you run `locale` in a new terminal window:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: what about in windows system?

Comment: @rony36 I'm guessing you should export these variables and it should fix these errors on windows as well. Have a look here on how to do it http://superuser.com/a/284351/79208

Comment: Awesome fix, thanks. Capybara `puts page.html` was throwing a similar error, and this worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem today. My LC_ALL was blank but everything else looked correct according to Lenart's answer. Changing LC_ALL did not fix it for me either.

The solution for my project was to update rspec from 2.14.6 to 2.14.7.

Answer (score 0):

My rails server was throwing this exact error from its logger class.

By upgrading to the Rails latest (3.2.13), it went away.  I just changed my Gemfile and did a bundle update tails.